# Middle ground between "I'll live with it" and "Bring it on!"?

Tags: expression-choice, conversation, french, mistranslation

The context is a typical conversation. You've settled for a course of action and expressed yourself accordingly. Then you get from someone a warning of sorts about potential risks or consequences stemming from your choice, along the lines of: "you are aware that this will..., are you sure that...". So it's either a warning or the person reacting to something and requiring acknowledgment of the concern. Then you may want **to retort** that you understand but that you're still right on course so to speak. The intent is to showcase the choice and your determination, maybe even your stubborn nature; it may be spirited or even defiant, yet not impolite nor confrontational; it is not about a burden, nor the surrendering to an ill fate or design; it has purpose. It respects, but does not concern itself with, the opinion of others. <sup>1</sup>

*Collins dictionaries* provides a translation of the French verb *assumer*(that verb in that language bearing the meaning I'm looking for) into an intransitive form: "to *[live](https://archive.org/stream/oed6aarch#page/n369/mode/1up) with it*". My first thought is to *live with an illness*, to *live on* despite a negative situation/choice, etc. It feels like a chore and further seems to cater to the warning rather than the choice. In BrE it seems it can indeed [mean](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/live%20on) *to endure the effects*; other [connotations](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/learn-to-live-with-sth) are negative. As for "[*bring it on!*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bring-it-on)", it just shows the other end of the spectrum: excitement, fearlessness in the face of the challenge, which connects here, but it also seems more fitting when there is a risk of bodily harm, such as with (contact)sports.

---

Is there a middle ground between "I'll live with it" and "Bring it on!"? What expression could be used as a reply in the context of that conversation and which better matches the tone and meaning provided(*take upon oneself willingly "all"* etc.)?

---

<sub>1. In so many words, it is the "*J'assume!*" in French(see translation on [*Collins*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/assumer?show)). Simply put, it seems often in speech [*to assume*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/assume) with no object is *to suppose*, whereas in French the (much)more usual meaning for the verb [*assumer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/assumer) here is *to take upon oneself*, as in "j'assume une tâche, un risque, les consequences de mes actes etc.". So much so an object may not even be required in casual speech: I assume(all). The word [*supposition*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/supposition?show) is the common ground and usually means the same thing in both languages. But even if the verb [*to assume*](https://archive.org/stream/oed01arch#page/516/mode/1up) can also mean *to take on* etc. in English, it doesn't settle this as in the context of the aforementioned dialog, answering "*I assume*" with no object often triggers the expectation for details about what you're assuming, hinting that this isn't idiomatic at all imho.</sub>

Comment: There are *lots* of things you can say: "Who cares!" "So what." "Oh well!" "That won't bother me." "I guess we'll have to see, won't we." "You only live once!" "Whatever..." "Big deal." "I'm not gonna a little thing like that stop me." ...

Comment: *, come what may.*

Comment: What the hell, ***I'm game***.

Comment: @Jim All of those imply defiance and not the middle ground OP is asking for.

Comment: I can confirm that "I'll live with it" is very common in BrE, and means exactly what you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say **the die is cast** means that the situation is past the point of return. (Some call it the point of no return). It neither comments on the outcome of the die being cast nor whether any particular possibility is good/bad, favorable/unfavorable, or preferred/unwanted.

Thus when someone warns of the possibilities, this neutral reply only says *the decision has been made* and that it will not be reversed.

(The die, in this case refers to the numbered cube used in games.)

Comment: Thanks! That's a great two for one! It doesn't carry the weight of Caesar's armies past the [Rubicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubicon), that weight is all cast in that die, but is most definitely _alea jacta est_!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest something along these lines:

> "I know what I'm getting (myself) into",
>
> "I'm ready to face the consequences"

or

> "I know what I'm letting myself in for".

Uttered on its own, I think most people would interpret "Bring it on!" as implying a direct personal challenge *to them*, not merely as a statement of the speaker's own readiness to accept the consequences of whatever choice they had made.

Comment: Thank you! An acknowledgement works indeed - even just "I know". Yes, there a confrontational element to _bring it on!_ and I had imagined it could even be something said just before a brawl; the more personal and the less people it's directed towards, the more it feels like "make something happen" etc.

Answer (score 2):

(Thanks for your concern, but...)

---I can handle it.

---I've got it under control.

Comment: +1 I can't see anything wrong with these.

Comment: @Mynamite- those seem somewhat defiant to me.

Comment: Thank you! These maybe have a "this is my business" idea and I guess the impact will vary a lot with the tone of voice here; but I like the idea of being in control! p.s. why that 3 dash format?

Comment: Two alternate continuations of the (optional) first line.  Plus sometimes my line breaks don't show up so "--" is just a separator.  Not part of the sentence!

Answer (score 1):

The expression *[It is no good/use crying over spilt milk](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/It%27s+no+use+crying+over+spilt+milk)* may fit in the context,

also *There's no point crying over spilt milk*:

> - something that you say which means you should not get upset about something bad that has happened that you cannot change Sometimes I regret not taking that job in London. Oh well, there's no point crying over spilt milk.

Comment: Thanks! It's useful, but you can't escape the "accident/disaster" connotation imho. If only what was spilt turned into obsidian stone or something lol; it would show that what could be perceived as a disaster - a volcano - is all natural if you actually _are_ the volcano.